# Java - Where to detect and catch SocketException

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have a Java Server/Client application that allows client input until disconnection, using a `while` loop. This is done inside a `ClientHandler` class object that extends `Thread` and uses the `run()` method, so each connected client is being communicated with on it's own Thread.

This is what happens so far:

```
public void run()
{
    //receive and respond to client input
    try
    {
        //strings to handle input from user
        String received, code, message;

        //get current system date and time
        //to be checked against item deadlines
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

        //get initial input from client
        received = input.nextLine();                

        //as long as last item deadline has not been reached
        while (now.before(getLastDeadline()))
        {   
            //////////////////////////////////
            ///processing of client message///
            //////////////////////////////////

            //reload current system time and repeat loop 
            now = Calendar.getInstance();

            //get next input from connected client
            received = input.nextLine();
            //run loop again
        }
    }
    //client disconnects with no further input
    //no more input detected
    catch (NoSuchElementException nseEx)
    {
        //output to server console
        System.out.println("Connection to bidder has been lost!");
        //no system exit, still allow new client connection
    }
}
```

This all works fine, and the `NoSuchElementException` is handled when a client stops running their program (as there will be no subsequent input).

What I want to do is detect when a client Socket is disconnected from the server, so the server can update a display of currently connected clients. I have been told to do this by catching `SocketException`, and I have read up on this exception but am still a bit confused by how I would have to implement it.

From what I understand (although I could be wrong), a `SocketException` has to be caught on the client-side. Is this correct? If this is the case, can the `SocketException` run in harmony with the `NoSuchElementException` that I already have in place, or will that exception have to be removed/replaced?

A basic example of how to incorporate catching a `SocketException` would be a massive help, as I've not been able to find any relevant examples online.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already catching the `SocketException` actually.  The `nextLine` call will (eventually) call `read()` on the underlying `SocketInputStream` returned by the `Socket`.  This call to `read()` will throw a `SocketException` (which is a subclass of `IOException`).  The Scanner class will catch the `IOException` and then return the `NoSuchElementException`.  So there really isn't anything more you need to do.

You can access the actual `SocketException` if you want by calling `ioException` on the `Scanner` once you've caught the `NoSuchElementException`.  Also, if you're trying to keep track of a list of connected clients then this will have to be done on the server side.  You can catch a `SocketException` on the client side but that would indicate that the server has disconnected unexpectedly which isn't really what you're looking for.